# Broken copy mode when vim / less hangs in Tmux

Tags: tmux

I use vim over SSH connection in Tmux, sometimes I forget exiting vim while the SSH connection is broken.

Now my copy mode became weird that I can only scroll to previous SSH screens instead of current screen. I guess this is because vim / less would change screen buffer somehow.

I tried `clear` but does not seem to do the job. I could only `:respawn-pane -k` to restore correct copy mode which is not desired.

Is there a way to fix this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Does `reset` help? Or `stty sane`? `tput reset`?

Comment: Thanks, I see that `reset` works much like respawning. Consider making it an answer.